# WordPress, не понимаю apply_filters

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Начал изучать написание плагинов для Wordpress.

Кусок кода из урока.

Добавляет в конце поста запись - плагин работает.

Не могу понять откуда берется значение `$content`. Если я комментирую первую строку, то код все равно отрабатывает.

Я так понимаю, что  `apply_filters('the_content', $content)` берет содержимое поста и дальше функция `msp_helloworld_post_footer` добавляет в конец содержимого текст. После этого `add_filter` обновляет пост с новым содержимым.

Однако, почему если убрать первую строку, плагин все равно работает?

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
function msp_helloworld_post_footer($content) {
$content .= "<div class='msp-helloworld-post-footer'><p>Hello, I'm your custom post footer</p></div>";
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'msp_helloworld_post_footer', 100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Базовая особенность WordPress - так называемые хуки, или зацепки. Вызов add_filter в вашем примере сообщает WordPress, что надо добавить фильтр на некое его внутреннее событие, называемое the_content. При возникновении этого события Wordpress вызовет вашу функцию, которую вы назвали msp_helloworld_post_footer.

И этот функционал будет работать вне зависимости от того, есть в вашем коде первая строка или нет.

Сама функция add_filter в момент ее вызова ничего не делает. Она лишь записывает в некий внутренний массив хуков WordPress информацию о том, что при наступлении данного события надо вызвать определённую пользовательскую функцию.

Аналогично работают вызовы add_action - они добавляют некое пользовательское действие, которое вызывается в нужный момент. Каждый хук (фильтр или действие) имеет свой список параметров, которые передаются в пользовательскую функцию.

Разберем более подробно, что и когда происходит в вашем примере.

Первая строка - берет некую переменную $content, пропускает ее через фильтр msp_helloworld_post_footer и возвращает результат в ту же переменную $content. При этом с содержимым поста ничего не происходит. Поэтому, есть первая строка в примере, или ее нет - неважно.

add_filter сообщает ядру WordPress, что в нужный момент необходимо вызвать вашу функцию фильтрации контента msp_helloworld_post_footer. На этом выполнение кода в примере заканчивается. Никаких изменений в тело поста не вносится!

Далее, в определенный момент своей работы, ядро WordPress приступает к обработке хука the_content (например, перед выводом контента поста на экран). Ядро просматривает внутренний массив хуков, обнаруживает там, что для хука the_content надо вызвать функцию msp_helloworld_post_footer и делает это, передавая параметром контент поста, который оно собирается выводить на экран. Ваша функция получает контент, обрабатывает его, возвращает в ядро. Ядро выводит измененный контент на экран.

Так, если вкратце, все это и работает.

Во многом именно благодаря наличию механизма хуков WordPress предлагает столь гибкий функционал.

Полный перечень хуков (а их более 2000) можно посмотреть [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/hooks/hooks-db).

Comment: msp_helloworld_post_footer($content) - Вот моя функция, У нее есть параметр $content, если я комментирую 1 строку - этого параметра не будет, и функция должна работать неправильно. Я что то не понимаю.

Comment: Или если нет $content, получается в функции $content будет пустой, - функция возвращает Текст. И этот текст путем add_filter вставляется в конце поста?

Comment: Ничего подобного. Ваша функция msp_ ... всегда будет вызвана с одним параметром. Независимо от того, есть первая строка или нет. Потому что ее вызывает WordPress, и передает туда ВСЕГДА содержимое поста в строке $content. А содержимое поста он берет из базы данных.

Comment: Вы можете использовать apply_filters, тогда ваша функция будет вызвана дважды - в момент apply_filters и в какой-то момент, определенный внутри ядра WordPress.

Comment: Понял, при событии the_content сам вордпресс передает в параметр функции содержимое поста. Спасибо за разъяснения.

Comment: Да, я дополнил ответ